# Is relative interior "everywhere"?

Tags: general-topology, convex-analysis

Consider a non-empty convex set $C \in \mathbb{R}^n$. I have the following conjecture: for all $x\in C$, there exists $y \in ri(C)$ (ri means relative interior) such that $y$ is in the neighbourhood of $x$.

The conjecture has the flavour of "the boundary is thin", or maybe "$ri(C)$ is dense in $C$"?

Comment: Yes, the relative interior is dense. Try to prove it.